# IE and Wijmo flex grid virtualization issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, wijmo5

This issues is IE specific. Whenever I click on dropdown inside the wijmo Flexgrid it is talking more than 6 seconds to open the drop down all the data is pre-fetched and we are not making any service calls to populate the data of the drop downs.

Comment: Have you asked at the wijmo support forums? It sounds like wijmo is using UserAgent sniffing (and branching on separate code) or it is not using documentFragment.... screen delays in rendering lists can occur when option elements are appended... Using the performance tab of the dev tool you would see a paint event each time an option element is appended. Using documentFragments you would see only one paint event when the select or ul is populated from the documentFragment.

Comment: yeah I tried to reach wijmo support team they asked me to share my code which is not possible since i work for a company and I'm not allowed to share the code. Thanks for information. do you think adding too many ng-if where you define the wijmo grid will slow the performance of wijmo?